# Beginner here: Need step-by-step help with amcl navigation through a pre-existing .pgm map

Tags: navigation, amcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello. I am trying to navigate through a pre-existing map .pgm file using amcl. I am completely new to ROS and do not understand some of the coding jargon on the websites of ros.org. If someone would be kind enough to provide step by step instructions online, that would be great. Please help. Thank You.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/256739/beginner-here:-need-step-by-step-help-with-amcl-navigation-through-a-pre-existing-.pgm-map/) by [rahul.pillai93](https://answers.ros.org/users/29614/rahul.pillai93/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2017-03-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

A step by step instructions can be found in [ROS Tutorials](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials) and [Navigation Tutorials](http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials).

---

Originally posted by [Procópio](https://answers.ros.org/users/1112/proc%C3%B3pio/) with karma: 4402 on 2017-03-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2